# Align specified number of Columns in a Row in AngularJs Material

Tags: html, css, angularjs, layout, angular-material

I'm using `md-card` to list the Items using `Angular Material 1.4.1` - `AngularJS 1.X.X`

I'm having a collection `ProductList`, it contains more than 10 items. Each `md-card` should be `200 px` width, based on window width the card need to align. If the card size exceeds the window width, the rest of the card need to come to the next row

My Code:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" layout-padding style="width:100%; background-color:white;">
    <md-card ng-repeat="item in ProductList">
      <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text layout="row">
          <span class="md-title">{{item.Name}}</span>
          <span class="md-subhead"> </span>
        </md-card-header-text>
      </md-card-header>
      <md-card-content>
        <p>{{item.Description}}</p>
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </div>
```

Now, I'm using `layout-gt-sm="row"`, so it displays all cards in a single row.

Kindly assist me how to arrange the cards based on Responsive.